# How can I conditionally sum values in R based on start/end dates in another column?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a table with rows for a rate, start date and end date, and I want to calculate the sum of any 'rate' values that are active on a specific day

```
df <- data.frame( startDate=c('2023-11-28', '2023-11-29', '2023-12-01', '2023-12-03'), 
endDate=c('2023-11-30', '2023-12-06', '2023-12-05', '2023-12-05'), 
rate=c(1, 2, 3, 5))
dates <- seq(as.Date('2023-11-27'), by = "day", length.out = 10) %>% map_df(as_tibble) %>% rename(myDate=value)
```

Graphically, say it looks like this:

[image: Visual Aid]

How can I add a column to the dates dataframe that represents the sum of the 'active' rates for each day?  For example, on 11/29 the first row is active because it started on 11/28 and ends by 11/30, and the second row (rate=2) is active because it started on 11/29 and doesn't end until 12/6.

I tried

```
dates %>% mutate(sum = sum(df$rate[myDate>=df$startDate & myDate<df$endDate],na.rm = TRUE))
```

thinking I could sum only those rates where myDate is on or after the startDate and before endDate, but I get a warning about "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".

Comment: I think I figured this out for myself... adding rowwise() was the missing link!  `dates %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(sum = sum(df$rate[myDate>=df$startDate & myDate<df$endDate],na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `dplyr`-canonical method:

```r
# convert df's dates to Date-class
df2 <- df %>% mutate(across(ends_with("Date"), ~ as.Date(.)))
dates %>%
  left_join(df2, join_by(between(myDate, startDate, endDate))) %>%
  summarize(n = sum(rate, na.rm = TRUE), .by = c(myDate))
# # A tibble: 10 × 2
#    myDate         n
#    <date>     <dbl>
#  1 2023-11-27     0
#  2 2023-11-28     1
#  3 2023-11-29     3
#  4 2023-11-30     3
#  5 2023-12-01     5
#  6 2023-12-02     5
#  7 2023-12-03    10
#  8 2023-12-04    10
#  9 2023-12-05    10
# 10 2023-12-06     2
```

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(startDate = c("2023-11-28", "2023-11-29", "2023-12-01", "2023-12-03"), endDate = c("2023-11-30", "2023-12-06", "2023-12-05", "2023-12-05"), rate = c(1, 2, 3, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
dates <- structure(list(myDate = structure(c(19688, 19689, 19690, 19691, 19692, 19693, 19694, 19695, 19696, 19697), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
# df2 is df with Date-class columns
df2 <- structure(list(startDate = structure(c(19689, 19690, 19692, 19694), class = "Date"), endDate = structure(c(19691, 19697, 19696, 19696), class = "Date"), rate = c(1, 2, 3, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```